# C socket programming: recv always fail

Tags: c, sockets

i'm trying to understand C socket programming for an university exam.
I made this simple example:

socket_server.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define SA struct sockaddr
#define MAX_MESS_LEN 16

int main(){
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr, cl_addr;
    int ret, len, sk, cn_sk;
    char cl_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN + 1], msg[MAX_MESS_LEN + 1];

    sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //creo socket TCP/IPv4 listener
    printf("socket created! :)\n");
    memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr)); //azzero struttura my_addr
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //famiglia protocolli IPv4
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); //in ascolto su qualsiasi interfaccia
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(1234); //porta del socket

    ret = bind(sk, (SA *) &my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)); //lego il socket alla struttura   indirizzo
    printf("socket binded! :)\n");
    ret = listen(sk, 10); //mi pongo in ascolto sul socket con massimo 10 richieste pendenti
    printf("socket listening (on any interface with port 1234)! :)\n");
    len = sizeof(cl_addr);
    printf("socket is going to wait for a request... zzzzZZZ\n");
    cn_sk = accept(sk, (SA *) &cl_addr, &len); //creo il socket connected per la richiesta in cima alla lista
    printf("socket accepted request! :D\n");
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cl_addr.sin_addr, cl_ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN); //converto indirizzo IPv4 cl_addr.sin_addr in stringa (cl_ip)
    printf("IP client: %s\n", cl_ip);

   ret = recv(sk, (void *) msg, MAX_MESS_LEN, MSG_WAITALL); //attendo la ricezione di tutti i caratteri della stringa inviata sul socket dal client
    msg[MAX_MESS_LEN + 1] = '\0';
    printf("received data (%d bytes): %s\n", ret, msg);
    if(ret == -1 || ret < MAX_MESS_LEN)
        printf("recv ERROR! :(\n");

    close(sk); //chiudo il server
}
```

socket_client.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define SA struct sockaddr
#define MSG_LEN 17

int main(){
    struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;
    int ret, sk;
    char msg[MSG_LEN];

    sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("Socket created! :)\n");
    memset(&srv_addr, 0, sizeof(srv_addr));
    srv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
    ret = inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.132", &srv_addr.sin_addr);

    printf("Trying to establish a connection with 192.168.1.132 on port 1234...");  
    ret = connect(sk, (SA *) &srv_addr, sizeof(srv_addr)); //faccio una richiesta sul socket
    if(ret != -1) printf("Connection established! :D\n");
    else printf(" connection error :(\n");

    strcpy(msg, "something to send"); //scrivo messaggio in una stringa
    printf("sending message: %s\n", msg);
    ret = send(sk, (void *) msg, strlen(msg), 0); //invio il messaggio sul socket
    if(ret == -1 || ret < strlen(msg))
        printf("send ERROR! :(\n");

    close(sk);  
}
```

And compiled it with:

```
gcc socket_client.c -o socket_client
gcc socket_server.c -o socket_server
```

Maybe it's a stupid question but the recv function in server always fail, there is an example output:

Server:

```
socket created! :)
socket binded! :)
socket listening (on any interface with port 1234)! :)
socket is going to wait for a request... zzzzZZZ
socket accepted request! :D
IP client: 192.168.1.132
received data (-1 bytes): ����
recv ERROR! :(
```

Client:

```
Socket created! :)
Trying to establish a connection with 192.168.1.132 on port 1234...Connection established! :D
sending message: something to send
```

What's the problem? I don't get it! :( I followed step by step, my teacher's guide.

I'm running on arch linux 64 bit ;)
Thank you for response!

Comment: Use `perror` instead of `printf` on errors (or show the `errno` and `strerror(errno)` somehow). Also, compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Read documentation of [recv(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) very carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cn_sk = accept(sk, (SA *) &cl_addr, &len); //creo il socket connected per la richiesta in cima alla lista
...
ret = recv(sk, (void *) msg, MAX_MESS_LEN, MSG_WAITALL); //at
```

You don't `recv` on the connected socket `cn_sk` to the client, but instead on the listener socket `sk`. If you would check the `errno` you would probably see `ENOTCONN`.

Comment: Thank you! i don't believe i've posted a question for such a stupid error, sorry :P